# how to process 1D cell array and comparing it's elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 1D cell array "Out" where each element describes a word and within this element is a vector that tells you which sentences the word appears in.

For example, if the word is test,trees and red which is assigned an ID of 1,2 and 3 a potential vector within the cell element of

Out{1} could be [1,5,8]

Out{2} could be [1,6,8]

Out{3} could be [2,8]

which means that the word test appeared in sentences 1, 5, and 8.

the word tree appeared in sentences 1, 6, and 8.

the word red appeared in sentences 2 and 8.

what i want to do is to compare test vector values with other 2 vector values and same for tree and red vectors in order to find out the common values(sentences) between them.in my case i have n elements

The out put should show that:

test and tree appeared in 1 and 8 together.

tree and red appeared in 8 together.

i want he answer regardless of representation, either matrix or in any other technique this logic can  be implemented would be fruitful.

the code i used for cell creation is:

```
 Out1 = cell(numel(out_words), 1);
 for idx = 1 : numel(out_words) %// For each word...
 K = strfind(sentences, out_words{idx});
 ind = cellfun('isempty', K); %// Determine which locations are EMPTY
 Out1{idx} = find(~ind);
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `intersect` command:

```
a = [1 5 8];
b = [1 6 8];
c = [2 8];

ab = intersect(a,b)
bc = intersect(b,c)
ac = intersect(a,c)
```

yields:

```
ab =

     1     8


bc =

     8


ac =

     8
```

You could loop over your output cells to find all possible combinations if that is what you want:

```
Out{1} = [1 5 8];
Out{2} = [1 6 8];
Out{3} = [2 8];

OccursTogether = cell(length(Out));

for ii=1:length(Out)
    for jj=ii+1:length(Out)
        OccursTogether{ii,jj} = intersect(Out{ii},Out{jj});
    end
end
```

(In the above code I assumed your cell `Out` is a 1xN or Nx1 cell containing the words)

Or, if you don't want empty entries in your cell array:

```
Out{1} = [1 5 8];
Out{2} = [1 6 8];
Out{3} = [2 8];

counter = 0;

for ii=1:length(Out)
    for jj=ii+1:length(Out)
        occurences = intersect(Out{ii},Out{jj});
        if ~isempty(occurences)
            counter = counter+1;
            pairing{counter} = [ii jj];
            locations{counter} = occurences;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: these statments are giving me error "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object"

Comment: it's working fine now, but i want to ask one more question, output is showing me lots of empty locations aswell like [ ] can i apply any check to omitt these [ ] locations?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad that is certainly possible, I have updated the code accordingly. The reason I used a matrix with empty entries at first, is that such a matrix facilitates finding the combination of words you used. For that, I have now added a cell `pairing`, so that you can see which two words are being compared. The corresponding entry in `locations` then show the sentences in which these words have both been found.

Comment: okay thanks mate, i used to do celldisp(occurences) it showed me 5. in the previous code i did celldisp(OccursTogether) which showed me the correct out put. what u suggest in the updated code what shoud i write in curly brackets celldisp(?)

Comment: `celldisp(locations)` should then give you the numbers of the sentences, while `celldisp(pairing)` shows you which two word 'numbers' were found in those sentences.

Comment: there must me some problem because celldisp(pairing) is showing lots of [1*2 double] output across 42 columns